# Magento; remove space before body class

Tags: php, magento

How does one remove the space before the class values?

In order to validate HTML, this:

```
<body class=" cms-index-index cms-home">
```

Should be:

```
<body class="cms-index-index cms-home">
```

This is happening on my home page.

Brad

Comment: is a leading space not valid? The w3c validator with a simple page doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not matter in the world of validation and rendering... but, just rewrite the [`Mage_Page_Block_Html::getBodyClass()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php#L157) method as follows:

```
public function getBodyClass()
{
    return trim($this->_getData('body_class');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using trim in the 1, 2 and 3 column page template files.